# Python Unable to reference a list in a calling class

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, object, dictionary

I have a class `foo` in which I have these two methods. `variableLevelDictionary` is a dictionary with strings as keys and lists as values.

```
class foo:


levels = []
specificLevels = []
variableLevelDictionary = {}

def __init__(self):
    self.createDictionaryOfVariableAndLevel()

  def getVariableLevelDictionary(self):
    return self.variableLevelDictionary

  def createDictionaryOfVariableAndLevel(self):

    variableList =  self.listOfVariables()
    levels = self.getAllLevels()
    specificLevels=self.getSpecicficLevels()
    variableLevelDictionary = {"aaa":levels,
                               "bbb":levels,
                               "ccc":levels,
                               "ddd":levels,
                               "eee":specificLevels
                               }
```

In `main()` function in the main module I instantiate `foo` and then I call this method

```
global variableLevelDictionary
fooInstance = foo()
variableLevelDictionary =fooInstance.getVariableLevelDictionary()
```

And then I do this

```
list = variableLevelDictionary.get("aaa")
```

When I print out the value of list I get None.

Can somebody explain what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: `variableLevelDictionary` is not the same as `self.variableLevelDictionary`

Comment: @PeterWood - thanks for your comment. So how do I fix this ?

Comment: @PeterWood - If I remove the self from self.variableLevelDictionary I get NameError : name 'variableLevelDictionary' not defined

Comment: Use `foo.variableLevelDictionary`. You've defined it as a class object, not an instance object, in your class definition. But what exactly are you trying to achieve, because it seems to me that your entire class organization makes no sense. Second, when you assign to variableList in `createDictionaryOfVariableLevel` it creates a local variable that gets lost as soon as the method is done executing. You would need to use `self`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga- thank you !I am starting off with object python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I notice is 3 things that could go wrong:

1) In method getVariableLevelDictionary you are trying to return self.variableLevelDictionary when in fact your class "foo" does not have have an attribute of the same name, this means that when you call this function you will get this error:

AttributeError: 'foo' object has no attribute 'variableLevelDictionary'

In order to fix this, you could try, inside your second function to do something like:

```
self.variableLevelDictionary= {"aaa":levels,
                               "bbb":levels,
                               "ccc":levels,
                               "ddd":levels,
                               "eee":specificLevels
                               }
```

2) You are calling foo.getVariableLevelDictionary when in fact you have the fooInstance, so perhaps you would like to call fooInstance.getVariableDictionary, which will fail unless you sort out  1)

3) You are assigning something to a variable named **list**, which is a Python bound word for the list data-structure and this is not recommended.

You could solve this by specifying another name , maybe **my_list** .

Let us know of what you try!

Comment: sorry I made a mistake in my code ! It is actually fooInstance and not foo !

Comment: could you print out the contents of the variable "levels" and confirm it is not None?

Comment: by default dictionary.get(k) will return None, if k is not in the dictionary. are you sure that you do not have a typo inside get?

Comment: Yes. I just printed out the whole contents as print(variableLevelDictionary) and it returns {}